# A mouse with near silent clicking noise with good build quality

Tags: mice, silent

I bought a lot of silent mice, but all of them kept failing after 6 months max. The best one I had so far was a "Hama Mirano".

Any better one out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice isn't very wide.

I've been using **Hama Roma** and it broke down after two months. After this time it was really hard to use the left button. The mouse was missing almost every click...

[JSCO Noiseless USB Optical Mouse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0042T7TBS) is quite popular. It has a lot of reviews.

The most important part ([source](http://www.amazon.com/review/R293R1LHIXXN7S/)):

> Ask yourself "What are you looking for?" If you answer a specific need
>   to have a quiet mouse to use when you actually need a quiet mouse
>   (I.E. late nights, libraries, class) and have a normal mouse to use
>   during all other applications. Then maybe you can splurge and get
>   this. But if your a gamer, playing a high intensity clicking game like
>   LoL or DoTA then either this mouse is not for you or you can expect
>   this mouse to last only months

This [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/32rsk1/wife_hates_the_clicking_looking_for_a_quiet_mouse/) may be helpful also:

> This is
>   the mouse I have been using for years now. The first one lasted around
>   4 years of intense gaming and I am using a second one now. I tried
>   several other but this one seems the best. Pro : Clic feedback on
>   finger, Nearly 0 sound (my gf doesn't complain anymore to the
>   clicking) Good balance although pretty light. Cheap. Found it at least
>   twice quitier than the G400. Con : The wheel still makes a little bit
>   of noise sometime, I solved it by adding oil to the mechanism. Not one
>   of those very well branded mouse with tons of feature, it's a mouse, 5
>   buttons, no macro and stuff.

The Nexus company has also several models:

https://nexustek.us/mice

Comment: Thanks! The exact same happened to mine "Hama Mirano" so it might be a brand issue.

Answer (score -2):

Apple's [Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad](http://www.apple.com/de/magic-accessories/) are awesome, super silent.

It's connected via wireless. In my experience, it has worked for two years without failing.

Comment: the old ones, new version is probably even better.

Comment: Could you provide some more commentary on the products you're recommending? One sentence and a link don't help much for people who will see this answer in the future.

Comment: Please see our [guidelines](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/60/57) for a high quality answer.